# Comparing the stopping times of two stochastic processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $f_1$, $f_0$, $g_1$, $g_0$ be $4$ distinct density functions on the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ with the corresponding distribution functions $F_1$, $F_0$, $G_1$, and $G_0$, respectively. The follwing relation is known to hold: $$F_0(y)>G_0(y)>G_1(y)>F_1(y)\quad \forall y$$
Define a random variable $Z_i:=\log\left(\frac{g_1(Y_i)}{g_0(Y_i)}\right)$

The stochastic process, $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_i$$ is terminated whenever $S_n$ 
exceeds either $A>0$ or $B<0$ *for the first time*, $n$.

Consider the following two cases:

**case one** $\rightarrow$ $Y\sim g_0$

**case two** $\rightarrow$ $Y\sim f_0$

> Question: Is it true that $E_{g_0}[I(S_n>A)]>E_{f_0}[I(S_n>A)]$? where $I$ is the indicator function which is $1$ when $S_n>A$ is true and $0$ elsewhere and, $E_{h}[\cdot]$ is the expectation of $[\cdot]$ when $Y$ follows the density $h$.

Thank you very much.

**ADDED**: If it would get any easier please take $B\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: Is the question clear? I will be happy if you could comment on this matter. Thanks.

Comment: What have you done? I am correct to understand to understand Yi are generated from h, but you are looking at evaluating it at two different density function.

Comment: @Lost1 $Y_i$ are generated from the subscript of the expectation; $E_{g_0}[\cdot]$, here from $g_0$. The likelihoods are calculated in the same way for both cases $E_{g_0}[\cdot]$ and $E_{f_0}[\cdot]$ as $\log(g_1(Y_i)/g_0(Y_i))$. So the question is; if the testing procedure is fixed but the densities from where we obtain the samples $y_i$ are coming either from $g_0$ or $f_0$, then can we conclude that relation at the expectation holds.

Comment: Where the hell did you get this complicated looking thing...

Comment: I am still confused, what does h do?

Comment: $h$ is nothing just a generic symbol to indicate the subscript for the cases $g_0$ or $f_0$

Comment: I see, interesting, will give it some sort.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is the expression $E_{g_0}[I(S_n>A)]$ supposed to depend on $n$? (It does indeed depend on $n$, but I'm wondering if that's what you want.) Or by $S_n>A$, do you mean the event on which the stochastic process stops because $S_n$ becomes greater than $A$ rather than $S_n$ becomes smaller than $B$?

Comment: @WillNelson Yes indeed as you said $S_n$ depends on $n$ and $n$ is a random variable. Lets assume I run the process under $f_0$ which has a negative mean (samples are coming from that) and calculate $S_n$.Say for $n=5$, $A>S_n>B$ is violated for the first time, with say $S_n>A$. This event namely $S_n>A$ is of our interest.Assume now that we run the same process for $1$ million times.Over $1$ million realizations, may be $900.000$ will end with $S_n<B$ because we run it under $f_0$ which as a negative mean and $100.000$ will end with $S_n>A$.Then $E_{f_0}[I[S_n>A]]\approx 0.1$.Is it clear now?

Comment: I would write this very differently. Almost always, people think of $n$ as an "index", so they make statements like, "$S_n$ is a sequence of random variables." You then define a "stopping time" random variable, say $N$. $N$ is just defined as $N\equiv\min\{n : S_n > A \text{ or } S_n < B\}$. It sounds like you are interested in $\mathbf{P}(S_N > A)\equiv \mathbf{E}(1_{S_N>A})$, where I've used the indicator variable notation I most commonly see.

Comment: I'd like to clarify your cases. Are the cases (1) $Y_i\sim g_0$ and $Z_i = \log\left(\frac{g_1(Y_i)}{g_0(Y_i}\right)$ and (2) $Y_i\sim f_0$ and $Z_i = \log\left(\frac{f_1(Y_i)}{f_0(Y_i}\right)$? In particular, are the definitions of $Z_i$ correct here? (That's not quite what you said in your writeup.) Also, you never mention that the $Y_i$ are i.i.d., which I suspect you mean.

Comment: @WillNelson thank you very much for your comments and time for clarification of the statements which might be not clear. $Y_i$ are independent and thats why we can sum them up with $S_n=\sum_i Z_i$. For both cases, namely case (1) $Y\sim g_0$ and case (2) $Y\sim f_0$, we have the **same** testing $Z_i=\log(\frac{g_1(Y_i)}{g_0(Y_i)})$.